# Content of horizontal scroll div is cut

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

I am inserting into my HTML using javascript. My code is being truncated/ cut off.

Here's my code:

```js
function feedbackDiv(feedback_id, feedback_title, feedback_content, feedback_author) {
  return querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    const data = doc.data();
    var feedback_title = data.title;
    var feedback_content = data.content;
    var feedback_author = data.author;

    document.getElementById("küchen_feedback_p").insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', feedbackDiv(doc.id, feedback_title, feedback_content, feedback_author));
  });
};
```

```css
.küchen_co {
  padding: 20px;
}

.küchen_feedback_p {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.feedback_container {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #212121;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
}

.feedback_container:hover {
  border: 1px solid #7ef6a9;
  animation: color_change 1s;
  background-color: #7ef6a9;
  color: #212121;
}
```

```html
<div class="küchen_co center">

  <div class="küchen_feedback_p center" id="küchen_feedback_p" style="display: none;">

  </div>

  <div class="noDataContainer_kfeedback_p" id="noDataContainer_kfeedback_p" style="text-align:center;">
    <img src="./broken_heart.png" width="80px" height="auto" />
    <p class="nothing_found_k küchenH">Es wurden derzeit keine Feedbacks abgesendet.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="feedback_container" id="feedbackDiv" style="width:300px; height: 250px; margin-right: 20px;">
  <p id="feedback_id" style="display: none;">${feedback_id}</p>
  <h1 class="" style="word-wrap: break-word;">${feedback_title}</h1>
  <p class="" style="word-wrap: break-word;">${feedback_content}</p>
  <p class="" id="feedback_author" style="display: none;">${feedback_author}</p>
</div>
```

But the content of the scrolling div is cutted:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/8f95tjojkbpku35/scroll.PNG?dl=0
~filip

Comment: from your image, the result does not look "cut off", you just have to scroll further to see the rest. You can make the container smaller (and/or your font-size). By the way, it'd be much more helpful if you gave sample code that displayed the scrolling issue; your 'placeholder' js text in a sole box is not very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all with further issues. The problem might be the following lines of code:

```
justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
```